# How to automatically select parent comment in my html reply froms?

Tags: python, django

Hello I am new in django. I created an comment system where user can post comment. Now I want to add reply to my comment. Basically I want to automatically select parent comment in my reply froms.  here is my code:

**views.py**

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView):
      model = Blog
      template_name = 'blog_details.html'      
      
      def get(self,request,slug):
         
          blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
          queryset = BlogComment.objects.filter(is_published="0",blog=blog)
          
          form = CommentFrom()
          context = {'form':form,
                     'blog':blog,
                     'queryset':queryset
                   }
          return render(request,'blog_details.html',context)

      def post(self,request,slug):
          blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
          form = CommentFrom(request.POST)
              
          if form.is_valid():
             comment = form.save(commit=False) 
             comment.blog = blog
             comment.save()
             messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Your Comment pending for admin approval')
             return redirect(reverse('blog-detail', kwargs={'slug':slug}))
          
          else:
               form()
          
          

          context = {'form':form,
                     'blog':blog,
                                       
                   }

          return render(request,'blog_details.html',context)
```

**#models.py**

```
class BlogComment(MPTTModel):
      blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
      sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)                      
      author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)                      
      name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=2000)
      comment = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
      created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True,null=True)
      updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,blank=True,null=True)
   
      CHOICES = (
        ('0', 'published',),
        ('1', 'pending',),
        ('2', 'rejected',),
        )
      is_published = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=CHOICES,default='1'
      )
```

right now I can only add reply form my django admin panel by selecting parent comment. I want to add reply through my html reply froms. somethings like this: [image]

**How to automatically select parent comment in my html reply froms?**

Comment: By "replay" do you mean "_reply_"?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat   I mean I want to add replay comment  of my parent comment. Right now I can only add child comment form my django admin panel. Let you explain assume post A have commnet1 now I want to add child comment of comment1 which I can doing from my django admin panel by selecting parent comment.